# How can I rearrange the equation to get $d$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following equation and for the life of me can't figure out how my prof came to the result. Could anyone please explain it to me step by step?
I can do the reverse, if I know $d$ but can't rearrange it without.

$$\nabla{f(x)}^Td = - ||\nabla{f(x)}||_2$$

where $x, d \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

$$d = -\frac{\nabla{f(x)}}{||\nabla{f(x)}||_2}$$

Thank you!

Edit: I phrased my question wrong... My question is way more simple than it was interpreted. I just wanted to rearrange the equation. Thanks for the quick answers until now!

Comment: You seem to understand why $d$ works which is good. This answer is non-unique, so you can't really "solve" for $d$ in the traditional sense. (You will get a myriad of solutions.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you are given $\vec{x}$ and $a$ and are asked to find $\vec{d}$ such that $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{d} = a$. You cannot do this in general unless some other information about $d$ is known.

For example, let $\vec{x} = (1,1)$ and $a = 1$. Then, $\vec{d}$ could be either $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ or any convex combination of these two, $(u,v)$ with $u+v=1$.

However, if you *know* that $d || x$, then this fixes the only solution.